# Lambda Function Not Sending Messages to SQS Destination?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform, amazon-sqs

Here is my code so far trying to figure out why I do not receive messages from the invoked lambda function. I believe I have added all the correct permissions for everything to work as well as ensuring that is everything is connected to each other. So if anyone could offer some advice it would be greatly appreciated!

```
#1. Creating IAM Permissions

resource "aws_iam_policy" "policy" {
 name        = "test-policy"
 description = "A test policy"

  policy = <<EOF
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement":[
    {
    "Action":[
      "logs:CreateLogGroup",
      "logs:CreateLogStream",
      "logs:PutLogEvents"
    ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
    "Action":[
      "s3:GetObject",
      "s3:PutObject"
    ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
    },
    {
    "Action":[
      "sqs:SendMessage"
    ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:694418723508:SQSqueue"
    }
   ]
  }
 EOF
}

#2. Creating IAM Role

resource "aws_iam_role" "role" {
name = "test-role"

assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
{
  "Sid" : "LambdaRole",
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
  "Principal": {
    "Service": 
      "lambda.amazonaws.com"
   }
  }
 ]
}
EOF
}

#3. Attach IAM Role Policy

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "test-attach" {
role       = aws_iam_role.role.id
policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.policy.id
}

#4. Creating the S3 bucket

resource "aws_s3_bucket" "bucket" {

bucket = "danysbucket"
}

#5. Creating s3 Bucket Notifications

 resource "aws_s3_bucket_notification" "bucket_notification" {

 bucket = aws_s3_bucket.bucket.id

 lambda_function {
 lambda_function_arn = aws_lambda_function.test_lambda.arn
 events              = ["s3:ObjectCreated:*"]
 filter_prefix       = "AWSLogs/"
 filter_suffix       = ".log"
 }
  depends_on = [aws_lambda_permission.allow_bucket]
 }

 #6. Creating Lambda Function

 resource "aws_lambda_function" "test_lambda" {
 function_name = "test_lambda"
 filename      = "main.zip"
 role          = aws_iam_role.role.arn
 runtime       = "python3.7"
 handler       = "main.lambda_handler"

 ephemeral_storage {
 size = 10240 # Min 512 MB and the Max 10240 MB
    }
  }

  #7. Creating Lambda Permissions

  resource "aws_lambda_permission" "allow_bucket" {
  statement_id  = "AllowS3Bucket"
  action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  function_name = "test_lambda"
  principal     = "s3.amazonaws.com"
  source_arn    = aws_s3_bucket.bucket.arn
 }


 #8. Creating Lambda Event Invocation 

 resource "aws_lambda_function_event_invoke_config" "example" {

 function_name = aws_lambda_function.test_lambda.function_name

  destination_config {
    on_success {
       destination = aws_sqs_queue.sqs_trigger.arn
      }
    }
   }

 #9. Creating SQS Queue

  resource "aws_sqs_queue" "sqs_trigger" {
    name  = "SQSqueue"
   }

   #10. Creating SQS policy

  resource "aws_sqs_queue_policy" "test" {
  queue_url = aws_sqs_queue.sqs_trigger.id

   policy = <<POLICY
  {
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Id": "sqspolicy",
"Statement": [
{
  "Sid": "First",
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Principal": "*",
  "Action": "sqs:*",
  "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:694418723508:test_lambda"
   }
  ]
 }
POLICY
}
```

`

Comment: You forgot to add your lambda code. Did you check that lambda does not produce any errors in cloudwatch logs?

Comment: How are you **invoking** the Lambda function? A Lambda Destination will only work if the function was triggered with an **asynchronous call**. If you are just calling `Invoke()`, it won't work.

Comment: @Marcin the lambda code is what I got from lambda blueprints and in the cloudwatch logs it shows up as successful